A Python argparse curiosity
Given the following code:
# parseargs.py

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("s")
args = parser.parse_args()

When I run this, it all works as expected unless the string passed starts with a dash. Obviously, python parseargs -string doesn't work, as argparse thinks it's dealing with a switch it can't find, but neither does python parseargs '-string' where I would expect the quotes (doesn't matter if they're single or double, by the way) should escape that. And, finally, this does work python parseargs '-string ' (note the added trailing space).
What's going on?

-string and '-string' are basically the same thing; it's interpreted as one argument passed by the shell. It's argparse that assigns meaning to that argument. And one-dash arguments are single-character arguments, and -string is shorthand for -s -t -r -i -n -g.

Not really sure what are you asking, the program contains an error. Do you know the end-of-options symbol? Example: python parseargs -- -string

In case it's not obvious, the shell processes and discards quotes before Python even runs. If you doubt me, see what 'ls' '-l' does.

This program can help you bit more understand what is going on:
import argparse
import sys

print(sys.argv)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("s")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.s)

Experiment with different quotes... Your specific issue is that -string is interpreted by argparse as -s -t -r -i -n -g set of options. To prevent that, put an end of options symbol before as correctly said by VPfB in his comment:
python3 parseargs.py -- -string

More info about POSIX standard end of options symbol is in this answer.

you could add python parseargs -- -string directly in code because one day VPfB may delete comment. And it is simpler to see it directly in answer instead of searching it in other places on page.
